# SonarQube with mixed unit tests files and source files

Tags: sonarqube

We've had trouble setting up a custom SonarQube server. The global analysis works fine, but unit test files are being analyzed and they trigger issues on the report.
For instance, we have hardcoded IP addresses in unit test files, and Sonar reports a security hotspot.

The arborescence is as follow:

```
component-a
    module1/src/...
    module1/tests/...
    module2/src/...
    module2/tests/...
component-b
    src/...
    tests/...
component-c
    src/...
    tests/...
```

I've tried the following parameters but it does not work, as test files are still being analyzed:

```
sonar.sources=.
sonar.sources.inclusions=component-a/**/src,component-b/src,component-c/src
sonar.sources.exclusions=component-a/**/tests,component-b/tests,component-c/tests
sonar.tests=.
sonar.test.inclusions=component-a/**/tests,component-b/tests,component-c/tests
```

Do you have any idea on how to make this configuration work?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
sonar.sources=.
sonar.tests=.
sonar.test.inclusions=**/tests/**/*
```

The test files should still be analyzed but only as test files (security hotspots should not be reported on them).